# How to use 'css-animator' in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, css-animations, ionic3

I have installed 'css-animator' through npm into my project by

```
npm install css-animator --save
```

I have also added below line in my index.html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

Now when I try to import AnimationService or AnimatesDirective in the app module, by

```
import { AnimationService, AnimatesDirective } from 'css-animator';
```

But i get ***error saying 'css-animator' module could not be found.***

Im following steps mentioned in this link https://devdactic.com/animations-ionic-app/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code  into app.module.ts declarations and provider section:

```
import { AnimationService, AnimatesDirective } from 'css-animator';
...
...
 declarations: [
    ...
    AnimatesDirective
 ]
 providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AnimationService
  ]
```